# avoid resetting interval on asp:timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, webforms

I am using an asp:timer on a master page of a windows form application to update the value of a label in an update panel.

The problem is whenever I click anywhere on the website it triggers the page build of the master page and it is also resetting the interval time of the asp:timer.

So for example : I have specified an interval of 60 sec, now if I don't click anywhere on the site it works fine but if I click( just use website normally), it is calculating interval of 60 sec after my last click.

How can I stop the reset of the interval property.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Are these other actions that you're doing causing postbacks (whether they be full or partial page postbacks), or are they actions that aren't interacting with the server?